# Combined Mapping with Spring Data JPA and Feign

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-feign

I have a **ShopMicroService**, a **CustomerMicroService** and a **CartMicroService**.

The ShopMicroService should work as an API Gateway and should be able ton control every other service. They are connected and routed with Netflix Zuul.

I want to be able to call e.g. localhost:8080/list, and see the data from both CustomerMicroService and CartMicroService. But I'm also not able to return two methods in my ShopController. How can I work around this?

**Shop2CartConnector:**

```
@FeignClient("cartmicroservice")
public interface Shop2CartConnectorRequester {

    @GetMapping("/list")
    public List<?> getCart();
```

**Shop2CustomerConnector:**

```
@FeignClient("customermicroservice")
public interface Shop2CustomerConnectorRequester {

    @GetMapping("/list")
    public List<?> getCustomer();
```

**ShopController:**

```
@ComponentScan
@RestController
public class ShopController {

    final Shop2CustomerConnectorRequester shop2CustomerConnectorRequester;
    final Shop2CartConnectorRequester shop2CartConnectorRequester;

    @Autowired
    public ShopController(Shop2CustomerConnectorRequester shop2CustomerConnectorRequester,
            Shop2CartConnectorRequester shop2CartConnectorRequester) {
        this.shop2CustomerConnectorRequester = shop2CustomerConnectorRequester;
        this.shop2CartConnectorRequester = shop2CartConnectorRequester;

    }

    @GetMapping("/getCustomer")
    public List<?> getCustomer() {
        return shop2CustomerConnectorRequester.getCustomer();

    }

    @GetMapping("/getCart")
    public List<?> getCart() {
        return shop2CartConnectorRequester.getCart();

    }
```

I already tried to call just one method and use both methods, but it still only shows of course only the list I am returning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, when you make an API call the `request handler` of your application will route incoming HTTPS requests to specific handlers methods of your controllers. Therefore, you cannot "return two methods".

But, if I understand you correctly you want to join two Lists and return them to the client - correct me if I am wrong :)  For this you can use `Stream API` that provides a `concat` method. For example

```java
@RestController
public class ShopController {

    final Shop2CustomerConnectorRequester shop2CustomerConnectorRequester;
    final Shop2CartConnectorRequester shop2CartConnectorRequester;

    @Autowired
    public ShopController(Shop2CustomerConnectorRequester shop2CustomerConnectorRequester,
            Shop2CartConnectorRequester shop2CartConnectorRequester) {
        this.shop2CustomerConnectorRequester = shop2CustomerConnectorRequester;
        this.shop2CartConnectorRequester = shop2CartConnectorRequester;

    }

   @GetMapping("/listAll")
   public List getAllLists() {
       List<Customer> customerList = hop2CustomerConnectorRequester.getCustomer();
       List<Cart> cartList = hop2CartConnectorRequester.getCart();

       List<?> list =  Stream.concat(customerList.stream(), cartList.stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());

       return list;
   }
```

But I would recommend to use a wrapper object to return two different object types instead of returning them into a single list. You may find trouble retrieving objects from a list which objects do not belong to the same implementation (casting and so forth)